# Remove a file from a Git Pull Request

Tags: git, github

I have added a local changes to an existing file into my PR by mistake.
I want to revert only this file without deleting this file locally.
I just want that it doesn't show up in the Pull Request.
I don't want to create new branch as many people have commented on other files in this PR.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

If you updated a file that already existed and want to remove it from the PR:

Assume you're working on a branch off of `staging`, and you PR'd a file named `validate_model.py`.

To remove this file from the PR *and* revert its changes, simply do:

```
git checkout staging -- validate_model.py
```

Comment: error: pathspec file did not match any file(s) known to git

Comment: ^ sounds like you're in the wrong directory or misspelled the file name!

Comment: I am also getting this error. I'm in the top level directory and used the copy button in the GitHub UI so know it is correct. If it says error: pathspec is it safe to assume that this file doesn't exist in main and that I can just delete it?

Comment: Instead of  staging, we have to use our `branch_name` and then perform the operation, I used it this way and it worked for me `git checkout campaign_post -- tests/api_tests_new/routes/trafficking/campaign/__data__/test_campaign_post.json`

Answer (score 47):

You could 'unstage' a particular file with `git reset` and then amend the original commit:

```
git reset HEAD^ /path/to/file
git commit --amend --no-edit
git push -f
```

This will not affect the version of the file in your working copy.

Alternatively, if you want to remove multiple files, you can reset the branch's head to the previous commit and create a new one:

```
git reset HEAD^  # move the tip of the branch to the previous commit
git commit -C ORIG_HEAD file1 file2 [...]  # list the required files
git push -f
```

Answer (score 32):

- Lets call your PR is from  `feature-branch` to `master`.
- Make sure you are in your `feature-branch`.
- Now lets say, you've made some unnecessary changes to `./abc1.py` and you want your `abc1.py` to be the same as master.

Run the following command:

`git checkout origin/master -- ./abc1.py`

Now if you run:

`git status`

You'll have the same changes as your `master` branch. Now you can commit your changes and push.

Comment: this doesnt answer how to remove file from pull request.

Answer (score 10):

There are probably many ways how to remove/undo file changes in your PR. 
I didn't find exact steps how to do this, so here it is:

**Scenario:**

Lets suppose that the file that you want to remove from PR is: 
 `C:\GitRepos\MyProject\SomeFile.cs`

This file is either modified or contains no changes (is the same as in master) but still is shown in your PR.

**Solution:**

**1)** Make sure that you have checked out the feature branch from which the PR has been created.

**2)** Search the file commit history:
`git log "C:\GitRepos\MyProject\SomeFile.cs"`

You will see multiple records in format:

```
   commit <commit id> 
   Author: <author name> 
   Date: <Date of the commit> 
   <commit message>
```

**3)** Find the commit before you made any changes to the `SomeFile.cs`. Copy the `commit id`.

**4)** Check out that commit using previously copied `commit id`:

`git checkout <commit id> "C:\GitRepos\MyProject\SomeFile.cs"`

**5)** If you now check the `git status` then you will see that the `SomeFile.cs` is now under pending changes.

**6)** The last thing that you need to do is to commit these changes by simply using:

`git commit -m "Remove the SomeFile.cs from PR"`

And push your changes. :)

Answer (score 9):

> git checkout -- the_filename

This will discard previous changes to the file and revert it to the last committed change.

You can learn more here [Git-Basics-Undoing-Things](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Undoing-Things)

Read the section Unmodifying a Modified File.

Comment: Just to clarify, first you need to get the previous commit id which added this file (use git log <filename>). Then just `git checkout <commit id> <filename>`. Then if you call `git status` you will see that this file can be checked in to remove it form the PR.

Comment: @Mr.Blond add this as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

To remove the file from pull request which was **added new** follow below steps from your branch,

`git reset HEAD^ path of the file`

then do amend commit, then do force push.

To remove the file from pull request which was **existing**(just modified in your latest PR) follow as below,

Open the file in any text editor (like Notepad or npp).
Replace (cut and paste) the contents of the file with unmodified version (likely copy from the  source latest updated or simply not having your changes).
Then stage and amend commit the file. Then do a force push.

Answer (score 3):

I assume what you mean is that you committed a change to some file `X` and other files `Y`, `Z` and so on. Now you want to undo *only* the change on `X`. You don't want to show it in the *push* (I assume you mean push instead of pull), so you cannot simply edit `X` back to how it was before (maybe you accidently committed a password or other secret in your source file or whatever...).

If there is one single commit which introduced your change in `X`, then it will be easiest if you use `git rebase` to "skip" that commit. Let's say `previouscommit` is the commit just before your change, and `brokencommit` is the commit you want to remove, then:

```
git rebase --onto previouscommit brokencommit yourbranch
```

If, on the other hand, the changes on `X` are mixed across many commits and/or combined with changes on other files, then (where `previouscommit` is the last "good" commit):

```
git checkourbranch
git -i rebase previouscommit
```

In the interactive rebase, chose the `edit` action for every line where `X` was changed, and edit it out manually. c/f `git help rebase` for more details, though it should be pretty obvious what to do.

Answer (score 3):

For me this command worked:

```
git rm -r --cached pathname/filename
```

Comment: Thanks for adding another solution

Answer (score 2):

You will need to know the hash value from the most recent commit effecting the file you want to remove from your Pull Request, hereafter , and the path to the file to which you want to undo all changes.  Then, execute these commands from your working directory:

```
1) git checkout <my_feature_branch>
2) git checkout <latest_commit_hash> -- <Path_to_file_you_want_to_remove>
```

Example:

```
git checkout experimentBranch
git checkout xxxx123 -- MyProject/Resources/Constants.java
```

With these changes, the file in question will revert to how it was at the start of your branch, i.e., before the first commit on your feature branch.

Answer (score 2):

Go to your remote/origin branch (not master) where you have pushed your changes (from where you have created a pull request). Delete that specific file from there.
In your local, stash your changes, then pull all the changes from remote branch which will remove that file and then pop your stash to get all your changes back along with deleted files.

Here are the steps:

1. delete file from your remote/origin branch and commit (won't be possible without it)
2. git stash
3. git pull
4. git stash pop

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to backup the workspace, then checkout the version before the commit (possibly by reassigning the branch tag first), restore the backup on it and then commit the right files/changes? That would avoid the extra commit.

Comment: Yes, this is a more better approach.

Answer (score 2):

**I have an easy solution:**

- Remove the git memory: git rm -r --cached .
- Add: git add --all
- Commit: git commit -m "<COMMIT_MESSAGE>"
- Push: git push origin <BRANCH_NAME>

Comment: Upvoted Thanks - but I feel `git checkout staging -- validate_model.py` by Jared Wilber is a shorter one that does the trick.

Comment: That's right. But my answer also serves if we want to clear all the added files to a PR. In that case we don't need to specify the specific file names, which may save a lot of time.

Comment: I was hoping that a * would work for all files in the accepted solution- let me confirm

Comment: sure @zip_lock_throw. Thanks for your help. I am new to StackOverflow and feeling good to see my initial answers are being reviewed.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Just click **Delete File** and you should be able to follow next steps easily

Answer (score 1):

In my particular case, they just didn't want to be reflected as: **File changes** (regardless of the commits to be added).

I just deleted the files and performed **Commit/Push.**

When updating the Pull Request, they are no longer reflected (as if they were never added).

I hope this can be useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Source tree app and reverse the hunk. If no file change was there then it would be removed from the PR.

Answer (score 1):

Alternate method, more tedious, but without using a git command:

Go to the diff comparison between the files, just copy the old file and paste it in your repository as it was before, then reupload. it will automatically remove it from the PR because the files are now matching again.

this is equivalent to the git command : `git checkout -- the_filename`

Comment: This revers all changes as well - which is not the intent but Thanks

Comment: But I want to revert package-lock.json file. Yes, copy pasting is possible. But too much of contents.

Answer (score 1):

This does the trick -

Switch to the branch where you need to change:

```
git checkout pull-request-branch
```

Overwrite the modified file(s) with the file in another branch, let's consider it's master:

```
git checkout origin/master -- src/main/java/HelloWorld.java
```

Commit and push it to the remote:

```
git commit -m "Removed a modified file from pull request"
git push origin pull-request-branch
```